# How to make hello packet in ONE simulator(DTN)?

Tags: routes, dtn

I am learning the DTN routing algorithms using ONE simulator.
I want to know how to make a hello packet for the neighbor nodes in ONE simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The ONE simulator discovers neighbor nodes automatically as long as they have their radio interface on and are within the radio range. If scanning interval is defined, discovery happens once every interval. Hence there is usually no need to make hello packets in the routing protocol implementations.